# Windows 10 font rendering problems

Tags: fonts, windows-10

Installing Windows 10 on a new PC for a friend. After the install, the menu fonts render poorly and in general fonts throughout all applications look really poor. Example:

[image: windows 10 font]

Tried upgrading the latest video drivers (did nothing of course). Verified that the monitor is set at its native resolution and DPI is at 100%. Anything else I could be missing?

Comment: I don't see a problem at all with the text. Can you further explain what you're talking about? My screen may be too small and I'm not noticing the same thing.

Comment: It looks like you have cleartype turned off. See [Turn off or on Clear Type Text in Windows 10](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-off-or-on-clear-type-text-in-windows-10.html)

Comment: Yeah what is crazy is that this image I uploaded looks just fine. I am severely confused at this point. On the screen it looks awful (and hence the screenshot should too). It does seem like a ClearType issue, but that is all enabled. Very odd.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to adjust the **ClearType** settings.

Go to Settings → System.

[image: System]

Then Display → scoll down to **Advanced display settings** at the bottom.

[image: Display]

Then under Related Settings, select **ClearType text** and follow the prompts.

[image: ClearType]

Answer (score 2):

They switched to different scaling in Win10 as opposed to Win8, and this is a major problem. There is a tool that reverts scaling algorithm back to Win8-style and the fonts look so much better after that.
Try googling Windows10_DPI_FIX for the tool.
This fixes 90% of the fonts, still there are some applications where the fix is not helpful, like pdf viewer inside Chrome browser. Have to find solution for these yet...